# CTRL + A Menu Apply Transformation : where to find in Python document

Tags: python, interface

I noticed that very often when I search for a command or something in the Blender Python API I do not find what I am looking for. I am not sure if I simply make a mistake or if what I am looking for is not available.

For example:

CTRL + A calls the Apply Transformation menu
[image]

I am after the command "bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()" but I would like to make a button that opens that menu.

And what calls that menu is not what I am able to find.

Can anyone give me a tip where such information is in a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one ( or other shortcuts ) :

- go to User ***File*** -> ***preferences*** -> ***Input***
- search for a key combination  "Ctrl  A"
- expand the shortcut for "***call menu***" under "***Object mode***"
- you can see the command is "`wm.call_menu`" and the name attribute is "`VIEW3D_MT_object_apply`"

since the shortcut point to an operator which should be under "`bpy.ops`", we use this line to call the same menu  :

```
bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name="VIEW3D_MT_object_apply")
```

Comment: Dear lord, the preference areas ... I should have thought about it.